# RAILS ajax file upload with progress bar & drag-and-drop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, upload, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for ajax file upload plugin, which would give me the possibility to display progress bar and upload files  using drag-and-drop.

The most convenient way for me would be to integrate it with paperclip.

The options that I've considered so far are:

- https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails
- https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader

However, I do not need to upload multiple files at once and I don't like the look of `jquery-fileupload-rails` widget either - I need a simple, up-to-date solution. It might be something using the FileReader API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), but I also need to support older browsers.

If anyone had experience with asynchronous file upload lately using some modern library, please share your thoughts :)

Comment: You can check Dropzone: http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: If you need fallbacks for browsers < IE10, i think its a good idea to give jquery-fileupload a try. Even if you don't need most of it's features.

Comment: Thank you @siekfried, `dropzone` turned out to be a perfect choice - very flexible and customizable and provides a lot of handy built-in callbacks :)